# Show $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i)<\infty $ if $\limsup_{n\to \infty }\mu(E_i)\leq \mu(\limsup E_i)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal M$ the set of $\mu-$measurable set. Let $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \subset\mathcal M$. Show that $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }\mu(E_i)\leq \mu(\limsup_{n\to \infty } E_i)\implies \mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\right)<\infty.$$

**1)** I first supposed $\{E_i\}_i$ disjoints, and thus $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i),$$
and then I tried to suppose by contradiction that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i)=+\infty $ but it's not conclusif.

**2)** I wanted to use the fact that  $$\mu(\limsup_{n\to \infty } E_n)=\mu\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=i}^\infty E_k\right)<\infty ,$$

but it's unconclusif too.

Comment: What does $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}E_{\color{#C00000}{n}}$ mean? (note the typo; $i$ should probably be $n$)

Comment: @robjohn: As usual ! $\bigcap_{i}\bigcup_{k=i}^\infty  E_k$

Comment: This isn't true without some additional assumptions: what if $E_i=E$ for all $i$, with $E$ a set of infinite measure?

Comment: @carmichael561: You're a genius ! Thank you :-) It's fine, I solved the problem.